# Configuring Datastream connection profile to an Oracle database hosted on a Compute Engine via private IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc

Since I am connecting via private IP, I chose `Private Connectivity (VPC Peering)` as my connection method

[image]

When configuring the private connectivity configuration, I am unsure as to what I should use as the `IP Address range`.

[image]

My VPC (`myvpc01`) has two subnets:

1. subnet01 (10.107.32.0/26)
2. subnet02 (10.107.32.64/26)

The Compute Engine is in subnet01

How do I allocate an "available" range in my VPC if my VPC has a range of `10.107.32.0/25` and all ranges are used by my subnets?

Comment: If you have only 2 subenet, you have room for another! Where is your issue?

Comment: you might want to review this documentation on Google https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-services-access#allocating-range